# Error while creating new expression in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created a new expression for my project whuch checks whether the loggedin user is older than 18 year but I am getting following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'over18'
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:14)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:36)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'over18' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:216)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
```

Following is my the class for SecurityExpressionHandler

```
@Component
public class CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler extends
    AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> {

    @Override
    protected SecurityExpressionRoot createSecurityExpressionRoot(
        Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation invocation) {
    NewExpressionsRoot root = new NewExpressionsRoot(authentication,
            invocation);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl());
        return root;
    }

}
```

and below is WebExpressionRoot

```
public class NewExpressionsRoot extends WebSecurityExpressionRoot {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDao")
    UserDao userDao;

    public NewExpressionsRoot(Authentication a, FilterInvocation fi) {
        super(a, fi);
    }

    public boolean over18() {
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) this
            .getPrincipal();
        String username = user.getUsername();
        if (username != null) {
            int age = userDao.findUserByUsername(username).getAge();
            return age > 18;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and below is xml for spring-security

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/admin"
            access="over18" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: Do I need to declare a bean in the xml itself or @Component would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception occured due to absence of following lines from the security xml

```
<security:expression-handler ref="customWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

which should be present in

```
<http><http/>
```